# Expression language not properly displaying empty ArrayList elements (Spring MVC controller)

Tags: spring-mvc, arraylist, el

I have a problem with my web application. I use Spring MVC as controller. In my JSP I have a form containing several inputs, each one of them will display the content of an ArrayList of String objects, which is a model attribute, like this:

```
<form>
    <c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="${myArrayListlength}">
        <form:input id="line${i}" type="text" value="${myArrayList[i]}" />
    </c:forEach>
</form>
```

The problem is that some elements of the ArrayList (even all of them, theoretically) might be empty. The inputs displaying non-empty Strings work just fine, the input corresponding to an empty string displays a concatenation of all the ArrayList elements. Let's say the ArrayList contains 4 elements, "Joe","Mark","","Bob". The form will display the following:

```
Joe
Mark
Joe,Mark,,Bob
Bob
```

I've tryied anything to get the properly empty inputs where they're supposed to, but in vain. I tried to use a ternary expression in the  attributes, like

```
value="${not empty myArrayList[i] ? myArrayList[i] : ''}"
```

but didn't work.

Thanks in advance to anyone who'll help me to shed some light on this.

Comment: does this happen when you change the loop to: `<c:forEach var="item" items="${myArrayList}" varStatus="status">
        <form:input id="line${status.index}" type="text" value="${item}" />
    </c:forEach>`?

Comment: The form inputs disappeared from the page :(

Comment: well, there is a difference between using spring form tags and just the ordinary ones. Maybe you don't need spring tags. try removing the `form:` part in the input tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jack Flamp suggested, switching from Spring form to ordinary form did the magic. Now everything's working smooth, without any need for ternary operators or other weird fixes.